# Laravel nested foreach returns duplicates

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to show all the user-owned courses.
The course details are showing okay, but when I try to get the user progress with a second foreach loop, it returns the same value for all of the courses.
NOTE: I can't get the progress from the first foreach because the progress is stored in the user_courses table and the rest of the course details such as the course name and description,are stored in the courses table.
Here's the code:

```
         @foreach($user->courses as $course) 
                <div class="course-flex-item">  
                    <div class="course-header">
                        <strong>{{  $course['title']  }}</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-description">
                       {{  $course['description']  }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="continue-button">
                        <button>Continue</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image-container">
                        <img class="course-image" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_256.png" alt="fasdf">
                        @foreach($user->user_courses as $user_course)                
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                                aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{  $user_course['progress'] }}%;background-color: #f64c71;font-family:'Montserrat';font-weight:bold">
                                    <span class="">{{ $user_course['progress'] }}%</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach

                    </div>
                </div>
        @endforeach
```

For example, if the user has 2 courses, one with 12% completion and the second with 30%, it'll show 30% for both of the courses.

var_dump($user_courses):
First course:

```
bject(App\User_Course)#1242 (27) { ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> string(13) "user__courses" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(6) ["user_id"]=> int(2) ["course_id"]=> int(2) ["progress"]=> string(2) "20" ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> NULL } ["original":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(6) ["user_id"]=> int(2) ["course_id"]=> int(2) ["progress"]=> string(2) "20" ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> NULL } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["classCastCache":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } } 
12%
object(App\User_Course)#1245 (27) { ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> string(13) "user__courses" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(8) ["user_id"]=> int(2) ["course_id"]=> int(3) ["progress"]=> string(2) "12" ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> NULL } ["original":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(8) ["user_id"]=> int(2) ["course_id"]=> int(3) ["progress"]=> string(2) "12" ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> NULL } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["classCastCache":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

Second course:

```
bject(App\User_Course)#1242 (27) { ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> string(13) "user__courses" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(6) ["user_id"]=> int(2) ["course_id"]=> int(2) ["progress"]=> string(2) "20" ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> NULL } ["original":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(6) ["user_id"]=> int(2) ["course_id"]=> int(2) ["progress"]=> string(2) "20" ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> NULL } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["classCastCache":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } } 
12%
object(App\User_Course)#1245 (27) { ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> string(13) "user__courses" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(8) ["user_id"]=> int(2) ["course_id"]=> int(3) ["progress"]=> string(2) "12" ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> NULL } ["original":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(8) ["user_id"]=> int(2) ["course_id"]=> int(3) ["progress"]=> string(2) "12" ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> NULL } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["classCastCache":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach($user->courses as $course) 
    <div class="course-flex-item">  
      <div class="course-header">
      <strong>{{  $course['title']  }}</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="course-description">
       {{  $course['description']  }}
      </div>
      <div class="continue-button">
        <button>Continue</button>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
      <img class="course-image" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_256.png" alt="fasdf">
                          @if(is_array($course)
                            @foreach($course as $user_course)                
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{  $user_course['progress'] }}%;background-color: #f64c71;font-family:'Montserrat';font-weight:bold">
                                        <span class="">{{ $user_course['progress'] }}%</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                         @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Ljaz, this is not even printing the progress

Comment: App\User_Course {#1242 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "user__courses"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:6 [▶]
  #original: array:6 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}

Comment: Ljaz this what it prints

Comment: please use var dump or print_r it is not showing all record

Comment: Added it @Naeem Ljaz

Comment: ljaz Youre on it??

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate second foreach. Then get progres like this

```
{{ $course->user_course->where('user_id', $user->id)->first() != null ?  $course->user_course->where('user_id', $user->id)->first()->progress  : 0}}
```